# Change the background color on rich:select items in richfaces

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2

In my application I am using JSF-Richfaces in web view pages. For searching by manual typing in select items I have to use rich:select tag.

```
<h:outputText value="Product" />
<rich:select defaultLabel="start typing for select"
                             value="#{accountSearchController.searchAccDto.accountProduct}" converter="#{productConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{accountSearchController.allProducts}" var="product" itemLabel="#{product.name}"/>
</rich:select>
```

The dropdown items looks like:

[image]

I want to change the background color of drop items as it is looks bleary as black in deep green. How do I can change the style of the drop-down items.

Comment: You are _**NOT**_ using PrimeFaces here... The prefix AND the image state otherwise

Comment: I said Richface. Moreover I just gave a snippets of the code and view page image. Please if possible let me know, how do I change the color.

Comment: No you did not say RichFace. Click the 'edited .. x minutes ago' above and look at your first post. Title, text and tag all showed richfaces and you corrected it wrongly... And sorry, have not used richfaces for over 10 years, so I cannot help you, sorry (other than hinting to use a browser developer tool and inspect the css)

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to the latest version (the colors were changed in 4.5.11) in case you can't just use the `selectItemClass` attribute - see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/index.html?rich/select.html).

Comment: Thanks so much. I have solved with your second option. But I have not found any release with 4.5.11 version